# Make an app that communicates with an app on a server over wifi

Tags: android, server, client

This is a very broad question, and I'm just looking for a pointer in the right direction more than a specific answer, but it's something I've always wondered and never known.

Lets say I have a program that I wrote, and I put it on a server. Then, I write an android app that I want to use to control that program (give it inputs, basically)

To boil it down even further, what I want to do is have a program that sits on a server, and basically make an android app that is just a gui for that program, and it can be controlled from anywhere, I guess sort of like a remote printing over Wi-Fi type of thing.

I really know nothing about this or even where to begin. I'd appreciate even some vocab words that point me in the right direction.

Comment: The *Wi-Fi* part is usually abstracted by the operating system of the device your app runs on – you want to learn how to write an app that communicates with a server over the *internet*. So essentially just like any other mobile app ever. And that is nothing special – so there already are tons of materials out there on writing apps.

Comment: What do I need to do on the piece that I've written on the server side in order to allow it to be communicated with?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: but wifi direct part is not the thing that I suggested for beginner user. since it is only support for android 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need basically three things:

1. A server machine with a program on it that can receive TCP/IP or UDP requests over WIFI
2. An Android app that can send those requests.
3. Some code that maps the requests to actions on the server machine.

There are a number of open-source projects that demonstrate the concept.  [Here's one.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/mark.harman/comp_wifiremoteplay.html)